# Problema para instalar o pouchdb

Tags: ionic, pouchdb

Estou com problema para instalar o pouchdb no meu computador não sei mais oque fazer.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

C:\Users\yagos>npm install pouchdb

> leveldown@3.0.0 install C:\Users\yagos\node_modules\leveldown
>   prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=10.14.2 runtime=node arch=x64 platform=win32)

C:\Users\yagos\node_modules\leveldown>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\yagos\node_modules\leveldown
gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\yagos\package.json'
npm WARN yagos No description
npm WARN yagos No repository field.
npm WARN yagos No README data
npm WARN yagos No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! leveldown@3.0.0 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the leveldown@3.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yagos\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-21T17_17_22_141Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Executei o Cmd com Administrador e dei o comando : `npm install node-gyp`, e o problema foi solucionado.